# VARCHAR length any reason to (2^n) - 1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I've been specifying the length `(2^n)-1` anytime I declare `varchar` or `nvarchar` but I wonder whether that it is a good practice or not. This turned into a habit for me actually to define everything as binary in software development because of the obvious reasons but SQL Server seems to surprise me sometimes (max length of nvarchar being not 4095 or 4096 but 4000 for example..) I wonder whether there is a value in what I'm doing.

Does defining the variables' length like this have any value? I guess it would have value in the old times.

**EDIT**: If it doesn't have any performance improvements, why does system views use these kind of lengths (you can check any of them)? For example, I checked `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and the columns are:

```
Column_name                 Type        Length
----------------------------------------------
TABLE_CATALOG               nvarchar    256
TABLE_SCHEMA                nvarchar    256
TABLE_NAME                  sysname     256
COLUMN_NAME                 sysname     256
ORDINAL_POSITION            int         4
COLUMN_DEFAULT              nvarchar    8000
IS_NULLABLE                 varchar     3
DATA_TYPE                   nvarchar    256
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    int         4
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH      int         4
NUMERIC_PRECISION           tinyint     1
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX     smallint    2
NUMERIC_SCALE               int         4
DATETIME_PRECISION          smallint    2
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG       sysname     256
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA        sysname     256
CHARACTER_SET_NAME          sysname     256
COLLATION_CATALOG           sysname     256
COLLATION_SCHEMA            sysname     256
COLLATION_NAME              sysname     256
DOMAIN_CATALOG              sysname     256
DOMAIN_SCHEMA               sysname     256
DOMAIN_NAME                 sysname     256
```

Comment: In theory, you could tweak your (fixed!) column sizes so rows line up exactly with regards to things like CPU cache lines, which might give a marginal improvement. In practice, even *with* fixed columns, this is wildly impractical at best, since you also need to take into account things like page header size. Certainly, just restricting all your strings to nice "binary" sizes won't cut it. And with *variable* lengths, having such sizes makes no sense at all. Use "reasonable" limits that make sense for your business data, not what you think computers would like.

Comment: As an aside, examine the "obvious reasons" why you're using nice round binary numbers in code sometimes. You may find that in many cases, it *doesn't* actually make sense, and defaulting to (say) 128 instead of 100 only looks better because you're more used to powers of 2, not because it actually improves anything.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the biggest reason that I use these binary lengths was me thinking that CPU would definitely `like` it and use it's cache more efficiently. But I would not use this if it's the other case and I would definitely choose 100 instead of 127 since it looks cleaner (for most of us :) )

Comment: For very high performance algorithms, taking the CPU cache line size into account might make sense, but if you're really at that level you need way more care than just making sure your data is all "binary sized". Controlling the exact alignment and placement of your data is hard enough when you control it all -- which in the case of SQL Server you definitely don't. More practically, suppose you had some kind of perfect row size which was a nice multiple of 2, and now you need to add one single `INT` column... are you going to add padding to X million rows and waste disk I/O? Probably not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `(2^n)-1` rules makes sense *if* strings are being stored using the C convention of single-byte characters terminated by a single `nul` byte. But so far as I'm aware, that's never been how SQL Server stores its strings.

In SQL Server, the length of the string is explicitly stored (either in the schema for fixed-length types or within the row data for variable-length types) and so, no, this convention does not make sense here.

---

When looking at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, almost all of the character columns are (directly or indirectly) using the [`sysname`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240(v=sql.105).aspx#sysname) data type - so it's not the case of them *repeatedly* choosing to use `2^n` sizes - they decided that `sysname` should be `nvarchar(128)` (very old versions of SQL Server used a much smaller size limit, about 12 characters if memory serves).

Comment: This has nothing to do with single or double bytes. A data page is 4KB. A field can't exceed the data page's size

Comment: The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - my point was about *where* a `(2^n)-1` rule *could* make sense. It only makes sense where you're trying to account for a terminator and want to make the total storage size be a (binary) round-number

Comment: Would the answer still hold if we consider the computer architectural elements like CPU registry caches, disk page sizes etc? I would at least think like CPU might take advantage of this when processing the data, does it not?

Comment: @sotn: as long as your data type is `(N)VARCHAR`, only the *actual* characters are stored without padding, so the discussion on what the CPU could or couldn't take advantage of is irrelevant. For obvious reasons, data storage in SQL prefers minimizing disk I/O over optimizing CPU access. Heck, Enterprise has page-level compression that decompresses data on the fly even in memory, which is very unkind to the CPU, but still a big win in many cases because it reduces I/O.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you check my edited question when you have time? What can be the reason for internal tables/views use these kind of lengths?

Comment: @sotn - I already addressed that in yesterday's edit - it's not that all of those tables are making the decision to use such lengths over and over again - it's that there's a single data type (`sysname`) that is used for, well, naming things. Yes, it's a `2^n` value but I do not believe that it was chosen, as such, for any performance related reason - they needed to change the older limit and whoever chose it probably did so because of an affinity for CS "round" numbers.

Comment: Oops, didn't get notification for that. Sorry to bother you again :)